# Dropbox sync api. Unable to download file from Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I am using the Dropbox Sync api for Android and worked out how to upload a file from my app to a folder within my dropbox. What I am looking for now is to be able to download the file from dropbox back to my app.

Can check the file exists :

```
DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

            if (dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
                                 // create file and upload to dropbox
}
```

Can someone point me in the direction of the method to download it back to app. (Using dropbox as a backup solution for users as well as SDCard)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to read the contents of a file from Dropbox, I think the answer is to call `dbxFs.open(testPath).getReadStream()` and then read the contents from there.

If that's not what you meant or if that doesn't work, would you please clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks. Sorted it and got it working but has opened a new issue